# Convert binary to decimal / hexadecimal / octal (java)

Tags: java, function, binary, converters

I want to convert `int number = 0b1101_1000;` to decimal / hexadecimal / octal.

I have searched the net and found that I can use function `toOctalString(number)` .

Unfortunately it does not work with this number format.

I guess it would convert `int number = 11011000`, but my format is way different.

Is there any function that would convert it easily?

Comment: `Integer.toOctalString(0b1101_1000)` works fine. What did you actually try and what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers in the machine are just numbers, they don't "have" a base (radix) like 2, 8, or 10.

The base only comes into play when you want a representation as a string of characters.

To the first point:

```
 int number = 0b1101_1000;
```

and

```
 int number = 216;
```

produce exactly the same result internally.  They are just different source-code representations of the same value.

To the second point: to convert to a string expressing that value as a decimal integer, use:

```
String s = Integer.toString(number);
```

or equivalently:

```
String s = Integer.toString(number, 10);
```

As a hexadecimal integer:

```
String s = Integer.toHexString(number);
```

or, equivalently,

```
String s = Integer.toString(number, 16);
```

(Octal should be obvious by this point)